# Connecting to a spatialite DB, querying, writing the queried result to a spatialite table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, spatialite

I am developing a plugin that connects to a spatialite DB , do some queries and outputs the results to a spatialite table. I had tried with the below code to connect to the DB and print the queried result to the console as first step.

```
from pyspatialite import dbapi2 as db
conn = db.connect('/home/farook/DB/cities.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = 'select * from test_pt'
rs = cur.execute(sql)
print(rs)
```

I could not see anything printed for the given query. Please tell me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cur.execute(sql)
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
     print row
```

or for one record:

```
row = cur.fetchone()
print row
```